# FirebaseStorage returning unknown error when requesting image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to pull in an image I have added to my firebase storage on an Android device. Every time this runs I get this error from the `onFailureListener()`

> E/StorageException(9646): An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
>   E/StorageException(9646):  Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

I have also changed the permissions on storage to have read/write for the time being to make sure that isn't the problem.

```
final ImageView test = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
StorageReference ref = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://my-project.appspot.com/test_image.png");
    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully loaded uri");
            test.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed loaded uri: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you actually running that code exactly, or have you replaced "gs://bucket/image.png" with your actual "bucket" (something like "projectid.appspot.com") and the path to the image?

Comment: Yea I have replaced that with my actual bucket name and file. Edited the code to better reflect that point.

Comment: Can you indicate what the inner exception is within the StorageException?
I just noticed that the httpresult is zero.  This suggests the request to get the download url was never made.  One way this can happen is if play services isn't updated on your phone.
You will know this is the error because adb logcat will show an error with something to the effect of "Storage network layer could not be loaded".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just noticed that the httpresult is zero. This suggests the request to get the download url was never made. One way this can happen is if play services isn't updated on your phone. You will know this is the error because adb logcat will show an error with something to the effect of "Storage network layer could not be loaded".

To fix this, update play services on your phone.  There are a few ways of doing this.  I find the easiest is to install the app "play services info" to see play services in the play store, and then hit update if its available.

Comment: This was the issue! Thank you.

Comment: Not a comprehensive solution. I installed the "play services info" app and checked if Play Services app needs update, but its not!

Comment: it happens to me in the BE side, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Update Google Play Services **on your device**, not in your gradle script (though do that, too).

After banging my head against the wall for about an hour due to only skimming benjamin-wulfe's answer as well as others on the internet, I came back and read it carefully. Hope this will help others avoid my mistake!

Comment: This does not even work for me. I think its something related to firebase. Still investigating the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem ,solution for this is :

- create a Storage reference-->

> ```
> StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs:<bucket address>");
> ```

- create a child for the storage reference

> `StorageReference spaceRef = storageRef.child("child name");`

Comment: As for me, I implemented the Firebase storage the right way but still the issue exist!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have up to date google play services to avoid this.

Also, Enable anonymous authentication in firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using the **Quick Start** Firebase storage sample. The problem was that the app wasn't requesting runtime permissions for storage on Android M.

So, try to check the storage permissions.

Comment: Fixed it. Storage permission was not granted in my case

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating StorageRef from **Download URL** not with the **Storage Location**.

```
String storageLocation="gs://bbeplayer.appspot.com/heart.png";
    String downloadURL="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bbeplayer.appspot.com/o/heart.png?alt=media&token=41a22961-daf1-433e-a580-e65144d34ab3";
    StorageReference reference;
reference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(downloadURL);
```

So I changed `reference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(downloadURL);`

to

```
reference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(storageLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Know it's too late But for me none of the above worked, the only fix was to update dependency for the Cloud Storage Android library to latest version which was 19.1.0.

The dependency added by Firebase assistant was old.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem recently and mine was because of the **permissions** in ***Firebase Storage*** i had not allowed read, write in the Rules so i changed them to [This Worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cidu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because I provided an invalid system file path for the [`FileDownloadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask) while calling [`getFile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#public-filedownloadtask-getfile-file-destinationfile)

Here the issued is raised as the downloadDirectory was invalid

```
String fileName = "...";
final File localFile = new File(downloadDirectory, fileName);
FileDownloadTask downloadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                               .getReference()
                                               .child("myChild")
                                               .child(fileName)
                                               .getFile(localFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error and eventually realized I was providing the wrong storage location. After correcting my code worked fine, so you can also try this:

```
Uint8List filename=(widget.imageData);
    ref=fb.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images}");

await ref.putData(widget.imageData).whenComplete(() async{
  await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
    imgRef.add({
      "url":value,
      "name":cond.data()["name"],
      "postuser-id":cond.data()["uid"]
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need upload another file with more size KB, thats work for me!