# Google map and firebase don't work together

Tags: google-maps, firebase, xamarin, storage

**UPDATE: This is the code that kills functionality of firebase.** If I try to download from firebase a couple of seconds after this code (waiting with await Task.Delay, no other code running), it starts sending the code -13000, httpResult = 0 exception.  The same request earlier works. Map works.

```
GoogleMapFragment gmf = new GoogleMapFragment(context, this);
FragmentTransaction ft = activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
ft.Add(mapLayout.Id, gmf, "my_fragment");
ft.Commit();
```

I wanted to have google map on layout in the same activity where I work with firebase. Map works, but somehow it interferes with firebase, which work only before creating Google map. Any ideas what can cause this?

**Update 2:** If I download small file before initializing google maps, I can later use firebase, so I 'solved' the issue in a little dirty way but at least I can continue working. After this 'fix' I get following error in the output but file is downloaded anyway. I must continue digging, for now I hope the worst is over...

```
error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: firebase-auth is not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode.
```

---

*Old version of question:*

I checked all possible answers here on SO for my question, but nothing brought me to right way. There's quite obvious output telling me that something is wrong, but I have no idea how to solve the issue. There's an answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396183/firebasestorage-returning-unknown-error-when-requesting-image) that one of possible reasons for HttpResult = 0 is that google play version on phone isn't actual enough. I used the method recommended for check and I have **Google Play services 11.5.18** installed on phone. I have **Xamarin.Firebase.Storage 42.1021.1 (10.2.1)** installed and using Visual Studio 2015. Quite often I had to clean and rebuild and it sometimes worked, but not this time. In android properties I have **Compile using android version 7.1 Nougat**. I created firebase account just recently, not knowing much about this, added it in google console to existing project (as I already use google maps), filled sha1 code the same way I did with maps. Added google-services.json and set it's build action on GoogleServiceJson. No more actions I know about.

Here is my code, I tried various ways to download, upload, but this one seems to be good example:

```
FirebaseApp fba=FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(context);
firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.Instance;
firebaseStorageReference = firebaseStorage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://alien-chess.appspot.com");
firebaseStorageReference=firebaseStorageReference.Child("settings.dat");
byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
firebaseStorageReference.PutBytes(bytes).AddOnFailureListener(new FirebaseFailureListener(this));
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="AlienChessAndroid.AlienChessAndroid" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application android:label="Alien Chess" android:icon="@drawable/Alien" android:largeHeap="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</application>
```

And here are what I think are important parts from the output window

```
Failed to retrieve remote module version: V2 version check failed
Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0
NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
....
Unable to create a network request from metadata
android.os.RemoteException
....
StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
```

There isn't much c# sources for visual studio and I can't read that easily recommendations for android studio as they are quite different for unskilled programmers.

Any ideas what other things should I check?