# Unable to save image to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my android app i am using Firebase Storage to save images i have set security rules to null then too i am not able to upload images and getting error.
Below are my error ,security rules and android code.Please let me know what i did wrong in code.

Logcat error : StorageException has occurred.
        User does not have permission to access this object.
         Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403

Security rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
   allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
  }
 }
}
```

Java code:

```
   galleryFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SetAvatar.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
                }
                else{

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(i,GALLERY_INTENT);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) {

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        uri = data.getData();
        cv.setImageURI(uri);
        final StorageReference filepath = sRef.child("Profile 
      Images").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(uri);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new 
     OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

       Toast.makeText(SetAvatar.this, "Upload 
                                     successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(SetAvatar.this, "Upload Failed -> " + e, 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseStorage returning unknown error when requesting image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396183/firebasestorage-returning-unknown-error-when-requesting-image)

Comment: But i am unable to post image could you please explain.

Comment: first make your `request.auth == true` then try again

Comment: I have changed it to true but still getting error.But i am not authenticating users.

Comment: Your security rules require the user to be authenticated. Since your code doesn't show that you authenticate the user in any way, it seems like the error message is correct: the user is not allowed to write to the storage location.

Comment: But in my security rules i have set request.auth == null so i think that doesn't require user authentication if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

change your security rules to:

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
   allow read, write;
  }
 }
}
```

But this will make your Bucket to be modified by anyone and I don't recommend it. However, you may use it for testing purposes.