# Cant upload my image to firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**so here my code of upload_iklan.java, there's no error but app always crashed when i try to upload it**

private void Upload() {
        if (mimgUrl != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mimgUrl));

```
        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mimgUrl)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);

                        Toast.makeText(upload_iklan.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(etFile.getText().toString().trim(),
                                taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                        databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(upload_iklan.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

here's the info

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Upload-1
    Process: com.example.latihan, PID: 8223
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.latihan-WUsFfg5SkqkBfTa4zb29Fg==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:148)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:457)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:257)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:198)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

By default, your firebase storage rules requires your user to be logged in before you can upload any files.

So, if you want to upload a picture successfully, either log in with a user in your android app or allow unauthenticated users to upload to the console like this:

1. Go to your Firebase Console
2. Click Storage
3. Click Rules
4. Change your rules file to this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      //allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you put this in your manifest? `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` @FarhanChatonJJanuar

Comment: Inside the `<application` tag, same level as app icon @FarhanChatonJJanuar

Comment: @FarhanChatonJJanuar hm, maybe check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396183/firebasestorage-returning-unknown-error-when-requesting-image

Comment: they said i have to update my google play service, but my its already up to date

Answer (score 0):

Change the rules of storage in firebase.

1. Go to firebase console
2. Click on Storage
3. Click Rules
4. Edit rules to the rule given below

   rules_version = '2';
   service firebase.storage {
   match /b/grocery-e7c47.appspot.com/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
   allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
   }
   }
   }