# Firebase storage exception: unknown error occured, please check the http result code and inner exception for server response

Tags: android, firebase-storage, android-10.0

This happens on 2 or 3 devices using my app and other devices don't have this error. I searched and all answers here tells me to upgrade my dep. version but i am already using the latest one '**com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.0**' and i still have the issue.

The error code is **"13000"** and the HttpResultCode is **"0"**

My uploading code:

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
    final StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child(getStorageFolderName() + file.getLastPathSegment());
    UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
        downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (!activity.isFinishing() && alertDialog != null)
                alertDialog.hideProgressDialog();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    setDownloadLink(String.valueOf(downloadUri));
                    // Update attendance
                    if (TrackingActivity.lastKnownLocation != null) {
                        attemptOperationTracking(TrackingActivity.lastKnownLocation, true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                handleUploadInterruption();     // Handle failures
            }
        });
    });
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(
            e -> {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //handleUploadInterruption(e.getMessage());
                int errorCode = ((StorageException) e).getErrorCode();
                int HttpResultCode = ((StorageException) e).getHttpResultCode();
                String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
                handleUploadInterruption("HttpResultCode:"+ HttpResultCode+
                        "errorCode:"+errorCode + errorMessage);
            });
    uploadTask.addOnCanceledListener(this::handleUploadInterruption);
    uploadTask.addOnPausedListener(taskSnapshot -> handleUploadInterruption());
```

I noticed that all devices have Android 10 on them so i used an emulator with Android 10 but the error didn't happen so is this relevant?

**My security rules:**

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write : if true;
      //: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Acccording to the release notes, the latest version is actually 19.3.0.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: This gives me a gradle error: ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.3.0

Comment: and by the way this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396183/firebasestorage-returning-unknown-error-when-requesting-image doesn't solve my problem!!